# Foul, foul! What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Despite being well-decorated, stylish, and sturdy
> I'm often dark inside, and
> When put into use, I am dark all around
> I am destined to carry Something (that will soon turn foul)
> To keep what is inside safe from what is without;
> Not more than One in my lifespan
> As It is often Something once precious and always remembered
> But It grows much worse as time passes
> Fouler, fouler
> Until It becomes no more;
> Even after It passes
> I still remain covered
> Filled and surrounded by dust
> Till the end of Eternity
> Or until I am pilfered
> By some wretched soul

What am I?

Comment: Phrasing a direct description of an object as a poem doesn't make it a riddle. Riddles have an extra layer of metaphor, misdirection, or wordplay involved - this has none of those.

Comment: What would be a good way to change this? Modify the title?

Comment: The problem isn't the title. The problem is that the question is *not a riddle*. You would need to change the majority of the question itself, not just the title.

Comment: I see... seems like I'm not that good at writing riddles :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because straightforward description of an object is not a riddle.

Comment: (Incidentally, this very site has a [variety of Q&A focusing on riddle creation and design](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle+puzzle-creation). I invite you to check it out, and also consider that your riddles will probably be better with more work & time put into them - so not posting 1/2/3 a day.)

Comment: I'm voting to leave open as I didn't find this just a straightforward description of an object - at first reading, the answer wasn't even obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is

> a coffin.

The lines are pretty much a direct description of the object:

> it is dark, it carries a body (which will rot over time), and is placed in the ground permanently (unless grave robbers dig it up).